# Fix algorithm for calculating normals

Tags: javascript, algorithm, opengl-es, webgl

I have the code to calculate the normal to the point, but it creates a strange artifacts (lines).
[image: my normals]

How to fix it?
If you use the normal of the blender, then there are no artifacts
[image: blender]
code( javascript):

```
for (var i = 0; i < d.polygons.length; i++) {
    var ind0 = d.polygons[i][0];
    var ind1 = d.polygons[i][1];
    var ind2 = d.polygons[i][2];
    var v1 = d.vertex[ind0];
    var v2 = d.vertex[ind1];
    var v3 = d.vertex[ind2];
    var vVector1 = self.vec3.minus(v2, v3);
    var vVector2 = self.vec3.minus(v1, v3);
    var vNormal;
    if (values.invertNormals === true) {
        vNormal = self.vec3.cross(vVector2, vVector1);
    } else {
        vNormal = self.vec3.cross(vVector1, vVector2);
    }
    d.polygonNormals.push(vNormal);
}
for (var k = 0; k < d.polygons.length; k++) {
    for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        d.normals[d.polygons[k][i]] = self.vec3.sum(d.normals[d.polygons[k][i]], d.polygonNormals[k]);
    };
}
for (var i = 0; i < d.vertex.length; i++) {
    d.normals[i] = self.vec3.normalize(d.normals[i]);
}
```

Comment: More generally I'd avoid polar spheres - they always have dodgy issues around the poles due to the small converging triangles. It's not related to your issue, but isospheres are less prone to banding problems.

Answer (score 0):

Should you not first zero the vertex normals before you sum. If the normal array has values in it already the sum will be incorrect.

Add this befor you sum the normals

<sup>Sorry I don't use the lib you are using and do not know the structure of the normal vec3 so can only work with what you have given, so I zero via minus, Would be best just to set to zero</sup>

```
for (var i = 0; i < d.vertex.length; i++) {
    // Only use the following line or the three after if vec3 is x,y,z
    d.normals[i] = self.vec3.minus(d.normals[i],d.normals[i]);
    // or guessing at normal structure
    d.normals[i].x = 0;
    d.normals[i].y = 0;
    d.normals[i].z = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your algorithm. You compute a normal for each polygon. Then you sum every 3 polygons. Then you normalize. How are the sum of every 3 polygons related to your vertices

If it's a typical polar sphere with a grid wrapped around the sphere then if we imagine there's only a grid 3x2 wrapped to the sphere like this

```
+-----+-----+-----+
|    /|    /|    /|
|0  / |2  / |4  / |
|  /  |  /  |  /  |
| /  1| /  3| /  5|
|/    |/    |/    |
A-----B-----C-----D
|    /|    /|    /|
|6  / |8  / |10 / |
|  /  |  /  |  /  |
| /  7| /  9| / 11|
|/    |/    |/    |
+-----+-----+-----+
```

Then looking at vertex B we need the average the normals of polygons 1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 8 and for A we'd need 0, 1, 5, 6, 10, 11

But AFAIK your algorithm isn't doing that. Am I mis-understanding it?

Answer (score 0):

Cross product don't return a unit length vector. You didn't normalized the per-face normals in your first loop. *polygonNormals* vectors have inconsistent size.

```
    vNormal = self.vec3.cross(edgeA, edgeB);
    vNormal = self.vec3.normalize(vNormal);
    d.polygonNormals.push(vNormal);
```